# How to viewed bookin.php on cpdeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm calling the file called booking.php with Codeigniter 4, but I'm getting an error. Although I add the following lines to Home Controller, the page does not appear, where am I going wrong?

```
public function booking()
{
$this->load->view('Partials/home/head');
$this->load->view('Home/booking');
$this->load->view('Partials/home/foot');
}
```

I'm calling the booking.php file, but it gives an error. as sitename.com/booking

```
public function index()
{
echoview('Partials/home/head');
echoview('Home/index');
echoview('Partials/home/foot');
}
```

but I can call index.php as above. Again, I can't call a different /urly like /booking /contact etc

Comment: You are using Codeigniter 3 language on your booking function - it should be `view()` not `$this->load->view()` and your index() function should be `echo view` not `echoview`

Answer (score 0):

load->view() changed on CI4,

You can use like this on index function.

```
return view('booking/index',$viewData);
```

Even if your file name is Booking.php, you must use lowercase when viewing.

I hope understood you correctly